# How to create a generic function to load a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, function, uiviewcontroller, swift3

**I have been trying to write a function that works with 3 parameters in order to load a view controller but I haven't been able to make it work.**

*I'm new into coding* and I am reading a tutorial that uses 2 view controllers (login & chat). In order to go from one to the other, the guide tells me to use this whether I want to log in or log out:

```
@IBAction func loginDidTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    // A
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)   
    // B
    let logVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginViewController   
    // C
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate   
    // D
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = logVC        
}
```

If I want to log in or log out I have to change 3 things:

1. **logVC** , *which I'd call **var1***, used in // B , // D
2. **"LoginVC"** , *which I'd call **var2***, used in // B
3. **LoginViewController** , *which I'd call **var3***, used in // B

In my newb mind, I imagined that I could create a function that contained the **"A, B, C, D"** lines and let me call it anywhere later just by changing **"var1, var2, var3"** parameters

---

This is what I first created using just **var1** and **var2**:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

    class Helper {
        static let helper = Helper()

        func loadView (var1 : String , var2 : String) {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let var1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: var2) as! LoginViewController
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = var1
         }
    }
```

I called it this way and it worked:

```
Helper.helper.loadView(var1: "logVC" , var2: "LoginVC")
```

---

Now, when I tried to use **var3** in line //B, inside the same function, Xcode underlines var3 and displays this error:

**Use of undeclared type 'var3'**

This is how it looked after adding a the **var3** parameter:

```
    func loadView (var1 : String , var2 : String , var3 : String) {

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let var1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: var2) as! var3
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = var1
}
```

This is how I would have called it if it had worked:

```
Helper.helper.loadView(var1: "logVC" , var2: "LoginVC" , var3: "LoginViewController")
```

---

I'd like to know if is it possible to do what I am imaging since I see functions as equations in which I can replace variables with the information I need.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Since your a self proclaimed newb i gotta tell you. Your so much of a newb you dont even know how to spell NOOB lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking. Do you *really* need 3 variables?

Actually, you just need one.

Let's see why.

Does the name of the variable really matter in `B`? Does the `LoginViewController` at the end of `B` really need to be there? No. The variable name is just a variable name. Changing it changes nothing about your code. It might make your code more readable though. The same goes for the `LoginViewController` as the end. That just causes `var1` to be of type `LoginViewController`. But this is unnecessary because you are assigning it to `rootViewController` later anyway. `rootViewController` is of type `UIViewController`, so you can just pass any variable of type `UIViewController`. To learn more about this behaviour, look up *polymorphism*.

Thus, your method is just this:

```
func presentVC(name: String) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper , it worked perfectly!

I thought it was necessary to change "var3" after `as!` since in the guide I'm reading, they change it depending if I am in the login view or the chat view. 

( If I'm in the login view, it is used an `as! UINavigationController` but if I'm in the chat view, it is used an `as! LoginViewController` )

I'll read about Polymorphism and keep learning. 

Again, thank you so much.